# Regexp group matching number

Tags: regex, emacs

I am using regexp replacing in emacs to replace the first term and third term's double quote to single quote. Input:
`"term1"    "term2"     "term3" "term4"`
(the term seperator is tab)

**wanted** output:
`'term1'    "term2"     'term3' "term4"`

I used below regexp search and replacement strings:
search: `"\(.+?\)"  "\(.+?\)"   "\(.+?\)"`

replacement: `'\1'  "\2"    '\3'`

However, the actual output replaces first and **fourth** term instead:
`'term1'    "term2"     "term3" 'term4'`

Is there any mistake in my regexp?

Answer (score 2):

Elisp regexps are greedy, so I expect your first group is actually matching the whole line, not just the `"term`". Try this instead:

```
"\([^"]+?\)" "\([^"]+?\)" "\([^"]+?\)"
```

Comment: thank you. I missed some 2-tab seperation and found this is the cause.